# Increment the value of a core-data model field

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I'm increasing the amount of a model field using the following code:

```
- (IBAction) counterButton: (id) sender {
    [model.amount++ stringValue];
}
```

It was working fine until I upgraded Xcode. Since then I've been getting the following error:

```
"Arithmetic on pointer to Interface 'NSNumber'. which is not a constant size in non-fragile ABI"
```

When the code was working it incremented the value by 1 each time a UIButton was touched.

any help would be greatly appreciated.
thanks

Comment: Break [model.amount++ stringValue] in simpler manner and try.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cant perform ++ on a `NSNumber`  which in an object not a primitive type.
Also it is an unmutable type.

If you want increase the value of amount you can try this:

```
- (IBAction) counterButton: (id) sender {
    NSInteger amount =[model.amount integerValue];
    amount++;
    model.amount = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:amount];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless `model.amount` used to be an `NSInteger` I don't see how that would ever have worked. The `++` operator doesn't work on `NSNumber`s. Or at least, it doesn't increment the value that's stored in it -- instead it would increment the *pointer* to the object, which isn't what you want.

Instead you need to increment the value "long hand."